# Performance of File Operations in Python

Tags: python, performance, file-io

Is it better to read an entire file before performing operations or is it better to perform operations while reading from the file?

If I was reading the entire file first, I'd store the information line-by-line in a list and if I was reading the file and operating on the data at the same time, I would be reading line-by-line and executing my operation after a line is read.

For the sake of the discussion, let's say the file isn't obscenely large. It would be nice to hear thoughts on small files and large files and if actions would differ. Also, I presume the operations also play a role; I'm reading URL's and downloading files.

Comment: what are you doing with the files after youve read them?

Comment: As a stylistic choice, I like to read a file all at once, like `with open(filename) as file: data=file.read().split("\n")`. Just because I don't like putting large pieces of code in `with` blocks, nor do I want to remember to `close` files long after I've opened them. But that's just, like, my opinion, man.

Comment: Nothing. It's read-only for my purposes.

Comment: For the case of fetching URLs from an URL list, it simply doesn't matter. The time spent on HTTP requests will outweigh any file operations by several magnitudes. So, use the more memory efficient and readable approach: `for line in f`

Comment: putting elements into a list using `readlines()`  then iterating over seems just  slightly slower than just iterating over the file object in a file that has 100 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, guys. Other than the inability to access the file while it's being read, are there any other downsides to having the file "open" for extended periods of time or caveats I should know?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you find out yourself for example using the timeit module

```py
import timeit

WORDS = "/usr/share/dict/words"

def a():
    num_lines = 0
    num_chars = 0
    with open(WORDS) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        num_lines = len(lines)
        for line in lines:
            num_chars += len(line)
    return num_lines, num_chars


def b():
    num_lines = 0
    num_chars = 0
    with open(WORDS) as f:
        for line in f:
            num_chars += len(line)
            num_lines += 1
    return num_lines, num_chars

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print timeit.timeit("a()", setup="from __main__ import a", number=100)
    print timeit.timeit("b()", setup="from __main__ import b", number=100)
```

Comment: I can certainly construct such a script and perhaps solve my single specific case but my intention was to have a discussion with people who are more knowledgeable than me about various scenarios.